# Highcharts not printing the line when there is empty data in the beginning

Tags: highcharts

When I try to print a serie with "no data" at the beginning, highcharts doesn't print the line that joins the points. But it does if empty data is at the end of the array.

This doesn't show the line between points 80 and 67:

```
series: [{
        name: 'On Track',
        data: ['',80,67]
}]
```

And this does:

```
series: [{
        name: 'On Track',
        data: [80,67,'']
}]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1qjp5be1/3/)

Is there any trick to print the line when empty data is at the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Highcharts requires to use the number or null value instead of empty string.

Correct values:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'On Track',
        data: [null, 80,67]
    },{
        name: 'On Track',
        data: [75,60,null]
    }]
```